# Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1)

Tags: openwrt, toolchain, dropbear

when I was cross-compiling for mips-openwrt-linux，I encounter an error showing below. It seems that protobuf using an opcode which was not supported by my compiler with mips1 opcode.

/tmp/cczgWQVg.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cczgWQVg.s:117: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1) `movz $2,$3,$4' /tmp/cczgWQVg.s:150: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1)` movz $2,$3,$4'
/tmp/cczgWQVg.s:169: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1) `movz $2,$4,$5' /tmp/cczgWQVg.s:181: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1)` movz $2,$3,$4'
/tmp/cczgWQVg.s:201: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1) `movz $2,$3,$4' /tmp/cczgWQVg.s:207: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1)` movn $2,$0,$3'
/tmp/cczgWQVg.s:765: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1) `movn $3,$2,$4' /tmp/cczgWQVg.s:1735: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1)` teq $2,$0,7'
/tmp/cczgWQVg.s:1797: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1) `movn $3,$2,$4' /tmp/cczgWQVg.s:1805: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1)` movn $3,$2,$4'
/tmp/cczgWQVg.s:2968: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1) `movz $2,$3,$4' /tmp/cczgWQVg.s:2971: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips1 (mips1)` movn $3,$2,$4'

I tried add CXXFLAGS="-D__MIPSEL__ -march=mips32" như gợi ý trên internet but nothing improved.(i know i'm using MIPS_R2)

p/s:I use "toolchain-mips_r2_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.